# Problem with running on lower versions Android

Tags: android, kotlin, biometrics

Have next funs in my class:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
override fun showFingerprintDialog() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) displayBiometricPrompt()
    else FingerprintDialog().show(supportFragmentManager, null)
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
private fun displayBiometricPrompt() {
    Log.d("some", "displayBiometricPrompt")
    val biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt.Builder(AppResources.appContext)
            .setTitle("title")
            .setSubtitle("subTitle")
            .setDescription("description")
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", AppResources.appContext?.mainExecutor,
                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialogInterface, i -> Log.d("some", "biometricPrompt") })
            .build()
    val cancellationSignal = CancellationSignal()
    cancellationSignal.setOnCancelListener {
        Toast.makeText(
                AppResources.appContext, "onCancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    biometricPrompt.authenticate(cancellationSignal, AppResources.appContext?.mainExecutor, authenticationCallBack)
}

private val authenticationCallBack = object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
    override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence?) {
        super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString)
        Log.d("some", "onAuthenticationError")
    }

    override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult?) {
        super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result)
        Log.d("some", "onAuthenticationSucceeded")
    }

    override fun onAuthenticationHelp(helpCode: Int, helpString: CharSequence?) {
        super.onAuthenticationHelp(helpCode, helpString)
        Log.d("some", "onAuthenticationHelp")
    }

    override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {
        super.onAuthenticationFailed()
        Log.d("some", "onAuthenticationFailed")
    }
}
```

Try to run on version P all works correctly, it calls the fun `displayBiometricPrompt()` and further down the script, everything works correctly.
But if I try to run on versions lower, throws the following error, namely when declaring a variable `authenticationCallBack`.

And get next error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mandarine.android.features.applock.unlock.UnlockAppActivity$authenticationCallBack$1 

at com.mandarine.android.features.applock.unlock.UnlockAppActivity.<init>(UnlockAppActivity.kt:119)
```

Comment: You should probably use `@RequiresApi` on both methods. TargetApi just supresses lint.

Comment: the problem is that you are declaring field with non existing (on lower API) class

Comment: @peshkira but in `showFingerprintDialog()` i have logic no only versions `P`

Comment: @Selvin ok, but I tried to use the annotation to this field, but it still does not work, and I need it `authenticationCallBack`

Comment: if the problem is the declared field, extract it to another class with an interface and load the correct implementation based on the current API. Or if this is not possible extract the whole logic in displayBiometricPrompt

Comment: You need to create instance of callback only on API >= 28